# Subsequence based normalization of n lists

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming

There are n lists of ordered integers, such that elements in each of those lists are unique (within the list). It is needed to normalize these lists, into (<=n) lists, such that the numbers of lists is as low as possible. (removing all redundancy)

We need to find longest subsequences of a subset of these lists, in order to eliminate redundancy. What is the optimal way to approach this problem?

PS: I am thinking along the lines of dynamic programming, but unable to find the recursive function/ states.

Example :
Given 4 lists : [1,2,3,4,8,12] , [3,4,8,10,12], [0,4,8,12], [1,2,3,4] the expected ordering that should be returned is :

```
[4,8,12] + [0]
[4,8,12] + [3,10]
[1,2,3,4] + [8,12]
[1,2,3,4]
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It's not clear to me what metric you want to optimize. I understand you have a set of n lists and you would apply some partitioning to this set and extract the longest common subsequence in each partition. Then you have some way of assigning a score to this partitioning and you are asking how to find the partitioning with the highest or lowest score. But I don't understand what kind of scoring you want to use.

Comment: For example, if your scoring is based on the number of partitions, i.e. you want to find the partitioning with the smallest possible number of partitions, you could take the partitioning where all lists are in the same partition and the longest common subsequence is in the worst case the empty list. Or if instead your scoring is based on the length of the longest common subsequence, you could take the partitioning where all lists are in their own partition, and then for each partition the length of the longest common subsequence would be equal to the length of the list in that partition.

Comment: Neither seems to be the result you want, so it would be helpful if you could give a more formal specification of what scoring you want to apply.